# Windows scale is affecting my application font

Tags: c#, hidpi

I'm having an issue on my program when i run it with scale 100% in windows settings the application looks good as i design it. But when the scale is set for example to 125%. I got a problem with graphics the font became more big.

I build different binaries with different AutoscaleMode value (None, Font and DPI). Then, I launch them with scale 100% and 120% (each time i log off to get the scale applied).

[image]

Here is the screenshots of different cases (in the textbox i writed the scale that is used):
[image]

I'm using MetroFramework for components.
Sourcecode is available [here](https://github.com/abdalmoez/serial-shell/tree/1b8dfc4c) (the last commit).
How can fix my application to look the same in different scale windows setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used SetProcessDPIAware and it fixed the issue and now the application works on different scale modes and there is only an issue with combobox size that change. I found already a ticket opened on git [here](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui/issues/97) for the combobox.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        SetProcessDPIAware();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();
}
```